# Can't use \input command with gedit-latex-plugin

Tags: latex, gedit

I've recently installed the latex plugin for gedit, to write my .tex documents in my favorite text editor.

But when I use the \input command to include an other .tex file in my main document, the editor highlight the line in white, and don't compile the document.

I thought the plugin don't recognize the \input command, or maybe it's because I haven't installed all the packages of TexLive (I've only installed `texlive texlive-lang-french texlive-latex-extra` packages in Linux Mint 17).

Know you how to fix it ?
Regards.

Comment: Do you mean `\input` instead of `/input`?

Comment: yes, sorry for the mistake